# Radcombobox inside Radgrid FormTemplate

Tags: asp.net, telerik

G'day,

I have a RadComboBox control inside of a RadGrid that is displayed when the InitInsert action occurs. I'm using Entity Framework as a datasource & the results contained within this are correct. My problem is that when I use findcontrol it returns nothing.

`If e.CommandName = "InitInsert" Then
            RadGrid1.MasterTableView.InsertItemDisplay = Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertItemDisplay.Bottom
            Dim query = From myTable In dbEntity.myTables Select myTable.Name, myTable.ID`

```
        Dim mineCompBox = CType(e.Item.FindControl("mineCompBox"), RadComboBox)
        mineCompBox.DataSource = mineCompQuery
        mineCompRadBox.DataTextField = "Name"
        mineCompRadBox.DataValueField = "Id"
        mineCompRadBox.DataBind()</code>
```

I'm having trouble finding any answers that reference FormTemplate without it being an edit form. What am I missing? :-(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by using an ItemCreated command. An example can be found here:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/find-controls-when-using-editcommand.aspx

The code for my situation was:

```
Private Sub RadGrid1_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemCreated
    If TypeOf e.Item Is GridEditFormItem AndAlso e.Item.IsInEditMode Then
        Dim dbEntity As WebsiteEntities = New WebsiteEntities
        Dim myQuery = From myTable In myTables Select myTable.Name, myTable.ID
        Dim EditFormItem As GridEditFormItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridEditFormItem)
        Dim myCombobox As RadComboBox = DirectCast(EditFormItem.FindControl("radDropBox"), RadComboBox)
        myCombobox.DataSource = myQuery
        myCombobox.DataTextField = "Name"
        myCombobox.DataValueField = "ID"
        myCombobox.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my computer in front of me to test it but I'm pretty sure that either:
1) You are not looking at the right controls collection
2) or the RadComboBox is not create yet or has **been created but the ID doesn't match** 
   so you cannot find it

Again not 100% sure. Maybe this can help you its a complete example: http://beecy.net/post/2009/01/07/telerik-radgrid-formtemplate-codebehind.aspx (maybe check you markup against this one)